# In-app purchase signature verification with PHP openssl

Tags: php, android, openssl, in-app-purchase, signature

In an attempt to follow some of the security guidelines for in-app 
purchase here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html 
I am trying to do signature validation on a server instead of in the 
app iteself. I would ideally like to use the php openssl libraries and 
it looks like code such as the following should work:

```
$public_key_str = file_get_contents("./pubKey/out");
$public_key_str = trim($public_key_str);
$key = openssl_get_publickey($public_key_str);
if(!$key)
{
echo 'Can\'t get public key';
}
$signature = base64_decode( $signature );
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $key);
var_dump($ok);
```

I know both my signature and public key are correct, but $ok is 0! Signature I try to use is string from the app purchase bundle. Guess my key is correct and the problem is in signature. When I try to decode it from base64 with: openssl enc -base64 -d -in signature -A > signature.bin, I have the string same with base64_decode(). Any ideas ?

UPD: also I don't really understanf what I should pass in openssl_verify() as $data ? My data looks like this:

```
$data = '{"nonce":5550262978898439313,"orders":[{"notificationId":"android.test.purchased","orderId":"transactionId.android.test.purchased","packageName":"com.ads.testbilling","productId":"android.test.purchased","purchaseTime":1308224646237,"purchaseState":0}]}';
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, i.e. instead of using backticks on every line indent it with 4 spaces (or simply select the lines and press CTRL+K)

Comment: Some tips here: http://crazyviraj.blogspot.com/2011/06/some-notes-on-implementing-in-app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at OAuth.php I think you can get it at googlecode.com
It uses openssl_verify() I think the $data they are using is an URL

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php