# In-app billing verification. Does server side code example exist somewhere?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

A lot of people ask how to write server side code
for in-app billing verificartion. 
Can anybody publish such code? Or know where such code is.
How to install in on the server?
There are  [similar subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371614/in-app-purchase-signature-verification-with-php-openssl)

I could not understand it.
I don't know php. 
Is it the next nightmare  which I must study?

Thanks for help and advices.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's pretty easy, you just need a small function like this in PHP:

```
function checkPayment($data, $signature)
{
    $base64EncodedPublicKey = "yourBase64PublicKey";
    $openSslFriendlyKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKey, 64, "\n") .  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    $publicKeyId = openssl_get_publickey($openSslFriendlyKey);

    $result =  openssl_verify ($data, base64_decode($signature), $publicKeyId, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);

    /*
    if ($result == 1) {
        echo "Success";
    } elseif ($result == 0) {
        echo "Verification Failed";
    }
    */

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: which $data and $signature do I send to the server? And do you by any change also have a function for MPL (PayPal) (I don't want to use IPN)

Answer (score 0):

Here is (uncompleted) python example:

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP

ANDROID_PK = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgmZW0GxWr0v1ndLfxHbV2ruWcmQ
<some lines skipped>
cwWjx5sWSahVp0M5aYRysSkGGjSxe1wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

def validate_google_play_signature(signed_data, signature_base64, public_key):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/546476/227024
    bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(public_key)
    rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(bio)
    pubkey = EVP.PKey()
    pubkey.assign_rsa(rsa)

    pubkey.reset_context(md="sha1")
    pubkey.verify_init()
    pubkey.verify_update(signed_data)

    signature = base64.b64decode(signature_base64)
    return bool(pubkey.verify_final(signature))
```