# Is InAppBilling Library v3 "breakable"?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I want to ask, if is the `inAppBilling` lib V3 reliable and if it is "breakable". I mean if is there something like `iApCracker` or `LocallAPStore` for iOS (via jailbreak).

Could you please give me any advice?

Comment: I have never heard of an "unbreakable" piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

If you verify Android in-app-billing transactions on your server and you don't store your public key in your Java source code it should be pretty robust and you should not have any problem.

To check transactions on your server you can use this PHP script:
[In-app billing verification. Does server side code example exist somewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215586/in-app-billing-verification-does-server-side-code-example-exist-somewhere/19147346#19147346)